# I want to specify a non-default layout for authentication errors in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to specify the layout in the following error.

- Route not found.
- Not authorized.
- Forbidden.

## File details

### App.razor

```xml
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <!-- TODO RZ9999 when Context removed -->
                    <AuthorizeView Context="authenticated">
                        <Authorized>
                            <!-- TODO ErrorLayout -->
                            <Error403/>
                        </Authorized>
                        <NotAuthorized>
                            <!-- TODO ErrorLayout -->
                            <Error401/>
                        </NotAuthorized>
                    </AuthorizeView>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                <Error404/>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

### Error401.razor, Error403.razor, Error404.razor

```xml
<PageTitle>Error401</PageTitle>

<h3>Error401</h3>
```

```xml
<PageTitle>Error403</PageTitle>

<h3>Error403</h3>
```

```xml
<PageTitle>Error404</PageTitle>

<h3>Error404</h3>
```

## What I have tried

According to the description in File details, ErrorLayout is used for Error404, but MainLayout is applied for Error401 and Error403.
I tried the following description, but it did not work.

### Add @layout

Error401.razor as follows but MainLayoute was applied.
Is @layout only valid for those with @page?

```xml
@layout ErrorLayout

<PageTitle>Error401</PageTitle>

<h3>Error401</h3>
```

### Add LayoutView

If Error401 and Error403 are children of LayoutView, they will be nested in the MainLayout and ErrorLayout layouts.

```xml
<AuthorizeView Context="authenticated">
    <Authorized>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(ErrorLayout)">
            <Error403/>
        </LayoutView>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(ErrorLayout)">
            <Error401/>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

## Questions

How do I write a Router to specify the layout in case of authorization and authentication errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom version of AuthorizeRouteView.
Create a CustomAuthorizeRouteView with the following changes based on the Blazor source AuthorizeRouteView.

```
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeRouteView : RouteView
{
...
    [Parameter]
    public Type NotAuthorizedLayout { get; set; }
...
    private void RenderContentInNotAuthorizedLayout(RenderTreeBuilder builder, RenderFragment content)
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<LayoutView>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, nameof(LayoutView.Layout), NotAuthorizedLayout);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, nameof(LayoutView.ChildContent), content);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }

    private void RenderNotAuthorizedInDefaultLayout(RenderTreeBuilder builder, AuthenticationState authenticationState)
    {
        var content = NotAuthorized ?? _defaultNotAuthorizedContent;
        RenderContentInNotAuthorizedLayout(builder, content(authenticationState));
    }
...
}
```

### App.razor

```xml
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <CustomAuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" NotAuthorizedLayout="@typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <Error401/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <Error403/>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </CustomAuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                <Error404/>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

With this content, I was able to do what I wanted to do without navigation with the original URL.

### Full source

- [GitHub](https://github.com/usausa/Example-Net-Blazor/tree/main/AuthenticationExample)

Comment: As a parameter well done!

Answer (score 1):

> Is @layout only valid for those with @page?

Yes sort of... You can also add it to a layout to to specify nesting.

FYI: 401 and 403 are both captured by `<NotAuthorized>`.

Use a component like:

```
public class RedirectToPage : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    private NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Href { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => Navigation.NavigateTo(Href);
}
```

You could expand this to include a return address etc.

Inside your `App.razor`

```
<NotAuthorized>
@if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    <RedirectToPage Href="/error403" />
}
else
{
    <RedirectToPage Href="/error401" />
}
</NotAuthorized>
```

Create the appropriate error pages using `@layout ...` of your choosing.

Comment: thank you. I was able to solve the layout, but the following problems occur.

- The URL on the browser changes to that of the error page, but I want to keep the URL that I was originally trying to access.
- After displaying the error page, I cannot return to the previous screen with the browser back  .
- If change it to Navigation.NavigateTo(Href, true), can go back to the previous page, but need to back twice.

Comment: @usausa, You cannot keep the URL you were originally trying to access since you redirect when accessing it incorrectly. However, if you want to be able to use the back button correctly, you probably want to use `Navigation.NavigateTo(href, replace: true)`, it will remove the unaccessible page from history stack.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way is to set the appropriate layouts in the `MainLayout.razor` file. Like this

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<!-- Page wrapper -->
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="flex flex-row h-screen bg-slate-50 overflow-hidden">
            <!-- Side Bar-->
            <SideBar/>

            <!-- Content area -->
            <div class="">

                <!-- site header -->
                <HeaderLayout/>

                <main>
                    <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 py-8 bg-slate-50">
                        @Body
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @Body
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorizing>
        <p>Hold up, lemma check you out.</p>
    </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeView>
```