# How to exclude login page from a token based authorization in Blazor Server App?

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor

I'm using JWT for authentication/authorization in my Blazor Server app. I have the following codes:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

        public CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
        {
            _localStorageService = localStorageService;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            string token = await _localStorageService.GetItem<string>("token");

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt");

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var state = new AuthenticationState(user);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));

            return state;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
        {
            var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
            var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
            var keyValuePaires = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

            return keyValuePaires.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
        }

        private static byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
        {
            switch (base64.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
                case 3: base64 += "="; break;
            }
            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }
}
```

**program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
```

**app.razor:**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(LoginLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    You're not allowed to see this content.
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(LoginLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I want to exclude login page from authorization. When the user goes into login page, because of null value of the `token` in `CustomAuthStateProvider` class, an error is shown in the browser's console. I tried to use `@attribute [allow anonymous]` in the login page. But the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `Login` page is part of the `LoginLayout` and you have specified the default layout of authorize route view to `LoginLayout`, So, If you'd like to exclude the login page from authorization then you should create the login page separately from the `LoginLayout`.

For more info about creating various layouts for different razor pages in Blazor you can refer to [Creating Various Layouts For Different Razor Pages In Blazor](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-various-layouts-for-different-razor-pages-in-blazor/).

Another solution is that create a `CustomAuthorizeRouteView` like what is done in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685521/4444757)