# How do I configure authentication and authorization in blazor server side?

Tags: authentication, blazor, identity

I have this code:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <RedirectToHome />
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

When a user is authenticated into my application, everything seems to work fine. The only problem I have is when I introduce roles.
I made one of my pages @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")],and when someone else for example a normal role tries to access this page, they are sent back to login. Can anyone help me? I want the authenticated but not authorized user to go back to the home page.

Comment: You should use custom authorize view. For more info, you can refer to this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685521/4444757